# perl bulk select DBI IN Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, perl

Need to retrieve 200000 records from a table and do processing on each record.  The database is oracle.  Currently Using fetch_rowarrayref method and  doing processing on each record.  For huge amount of record is it efficient to have a  fetch limit like 5000 records and looping.  Mysql has a LIMIT keyword but oracle doesn't have it.   Not sure how in dbi i can do it.

Fetch 5000 records into a array
    Do the processing from the array
 Fetch again till it reached 100000 records

Comment: Oracle SQL does have [`ROWNUM`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html), though.

Comment: Indeed Oracle has ROWNUM and ROWID for getting specific and rows from database in particular range.

Comment: The usual approach for Oracle is to use BULK COLLECT with a LIMIT clause. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865295/oracle-bulk-collect-issue for an example. I'm not sure whether this is viable from Perl, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links.  Will try out if i can access it from perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pagination will not be more efficient than what you are doing.  The point of pagination would be to avoid running out of memory, but if you are not (and Oracle should not with DBD::Oracle) then there is nothing gained by that.

If this operation is too slow, then you have several basic options.

1. Do the dump closer to the database (less latency).
2. Select less data.
3. Have several processes querying in parallel.
4. Use a special purpose bulk export tool.
5. Reset expectations so that you can live with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info . I am more interested in knowing any specific method in PERL DBI that i can use for fetching 10000 rows each time rather than each fetch returns 1 row.

Comment: @Arav Transparently built in behind the scenes.  See http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.616/DBI.pm#RowCacheSize for how to set the amount that is fetched at once.  (Not all databases support that, but Oracle definitely does.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Will use Row cache size

Answer (score -1):

Your task looks like pagination in fetching data and processing on it,  to write a pagination type query

```
select *
 from (
select /*+ first_rows(25) */
  your_columns,
  row_number() 
  over (order by something unique)rn
 from your_tables )
where rn between :n and :m 
order by rn;
```

:n = Starting Row 
:m = End Row
rn = Column to Perform Sorting

for more information u can refer to [link #1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html) or [link #2](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_pagination.htm)

Comment: This does NOT answer the question asked.  Not even close.

Comment: @btilly   Read the question again , he said ( Mysql has a LIMIT keyword but oracle doesn't have it. Not sure how in dbi i can do it.) so i explain , how he can perform pagination first and do processing on data and move to further dataset ....

Comment: Yes, I did.  The question asked is, **IS PAGINATION FASTER** (and if it is, how to do it).  The answer is **NO** (making the how irrelevant).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info . I am more interested in knowing any specific method in PERL DBI that i can use for fetching 10000 rows each time rather than each fetch returns 1 row.